# verificação pelo método hasFocus() em tag <a>

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, boa tarde :)
tenho o seguindo código HTML:

```
<section class="sectionQuemSomos">
   <a class="iconQuemSomos" id="QuemSomos">
     <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 80px" src="assets/img/icos/Icone_Quemsomos.png">
   </a>
</section>
```

e o seguinte código JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var quemSomos = document.getElementById("QuemSomos");

  $(document).addEventListener('focus', function(){
    if (quemSomos === document.activeElement){
    alert("efds");
    }
  });
});
```

Por mais simples que pareça, não estou conseguindo fazer com que essa verificação if retorne true e entre em seu bloco de código. Eu clico na tag  para dá-la o foco mas não é exibido nenhum alert, logo eu sei que não está funcionando essa verificação.

Estou tentando implementar esse eventListener para que possa ocorrer essa verificação após o documento está pronto.

Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Tente assim: `if ($(quemSomos).is(":focus")){`

Comment: não deu certo =\

Comment: Vc está querendo verificar se tem foco no carregamento da página. Isso não dá certo. Tem que usar algum evento.

Comment: pois é. Estou nesse momento pensando nisso... Você sabe como eu poderia usar esse evento?

Comment: bem, agora vc mudou a pergunta e as respostas ficaram sem sentido, deveria colocar uma nota dizendo que editou, pois vocÊ colocou a sugestão da minha resposta, ai parece que respondi sem ler sua pergunta :P

Comment: Desculpa! não tenho muito costume com esse "fórum" . hauhusa falha minha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir fazer essa verificação no carregamento da página com o elemento `<a>`, pois ele não é *auto-focável* e nem focável sem o atributo `href`.

Não vejo razão de usar a tag `a` desta forma, sem ser um link clicável, mas se é isso que quer, tem que usar o atributo `tabindex` para que o elemento se torne focável:

```
<a class="iconQuemSomos" id="QuemSomos" tabindex="0">
```

Desta forma você pode detectar o foco usando o evento `focus`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   "use strict";
   $("#QuemSomos").on("focus",function(){
      console.log("foco");
   });
});
```

Comment: Funcionou! a ideia é ter uma imagem onde o usuário poderá clicar nela e algum evento ocorrerá com isso mas eu não soube lidar com esse click na imagem mas sabia que poderia trabalhar com o focus na tag <a> mas não sabia que ela se torna não-focável na ausência do href

Answer (score 1):

`hasFocus()` é um método do objeto `document`: [developer.mozilla.org/Document/hasFocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus)

Para verificar em `javascript` se um elemento tem focus, compara com o elemento em `document.activeElement`, que retorna o elemento atual com focus:

```
var quemSomos = document.getElementById("QuemSomos");
if (quemSomos === document.activeElement){
    alert("foco");
}
```

Se preferir usar `jQuery`, pode validar assim:

```
if ($('#QuemSomos').is(":focus")){
    alert("foco");
}
```

Comment: sem resultados. só uma pergunta: a tag <a> por natureza ganha o foco quando você clica nela, certo?

Comment: Mas uma pergunta sobre seu código: se está no bloco `$(document).ready` significa que assim que o documento estiver pronto, o focus tem de estar no elemento "QuemSomos". Alguma coisa faz o focus ir para lá? Senão nunca vai retorna `true`, e ai o não é o `if` mas o fluxo da página

Comment: Sim mas deve ser um instante, porque o link (tag `<a>`) já vai direcionar para outra página ou outro local